# About Vue two-way data bindings: what if form field content doesn't come from direct user input?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

So I've got some code like this:

```
<input name="date" v-model="date" id="date" type="text" value="" />
```

...then somewhere else:

```
<li><b>Date:</b> {{ date }}</li>
```

...And Vue:

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#form'
  ,data:{
    date:''
  }
});
```

Normally, this code will update li's content in real time while the user types into the input field. But in my case, I've assigned a javascript date picker to it, and the li's content doesn't get updated. I guess because there are no keyup (or the like) events. How to elegantly overcome this lovely issue?

Comment: A general solution to this problem is to use the callback/event provided by the plugin to manually trigger an `input` event on the element, which in turn will cause the vm to pick up the change.  See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my own answer comes from @numbers1311407's suggestion. Essentially, I hooked into the plugins events from the `mounted` Vue's function, and then used the `$set` instance method to change the property I needed. So, to recap, here's my html:

```
<input name="project[deadline]" v-model="form.project.deadline" data-toggle="datepicker" id="project-deadline" type="text" value="" />
```

And here's my js:

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#form'
  ,data:{
    form:{ // for tech reasons I'm using several nested empty objects here
      contact:{}
      project:{} 
      component:{}
      // [...] other several objects ...
    }
  }
  ,mounted: function(){
    $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').on('hide.datepicker', function (e) {
      _.delay(function(){ // from lodash.js
        this.$set(this.form.project, 'deadline', $(e.target).val());
      }.bind(this), 150); // because the plugin's event fires before the field gets updated
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Note that I'm slightly delaying the assignment, but this is not a Vue thing. It's just because the plugin's event I'm using fires just before changing the value, and the plugin itself doesn't expose any event that fires after. So I have to wait a bit for the field to be updated and then I can pick up its value and assign it to Vue's model.

For reference, the plugin currently in use is [this one](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use components for it, which will handle such scenarios gracefully.
For example using [`vuejs-datepicker`](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    vuejsDatepicker
  },
  data: {
    date: ''
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:0!important;bottom:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>
<div id="app">
  <vuejs-datepicker v-model="date"></vuejs-datepicker>
  <br/>
  <p><b>Date:</b> {{ date }}</p>
</div>
```

You can also create your own [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) for it and use it anywhere in your app.